# Should useEffect only be used inside customHooks?

Tags: reactjs

For the separation of concern, should we always put the useEffect hook inside custom hook ?

Is it ok if we have a a useEffect in the component and not in useComponent ?

I explain with some lines of code :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const updateTitle = () => {
      navigation.setOptions({
        title,
      });
    };

    updateTitle();
  }, [title]);
```

Imagine I have the following arch :

- custom hooks
- useMyPage
- components
- myPage

Should we ALWAYS put useEffect in the custom hook ?
Is it a mistake if we put one useEffect in myPage component ?

I would like to have a better view of how to structure a react app by respecting the separation of concern.

Thanks for any enlightning

Comment: You can use it in component. It is meant for side effects. 
In your case when title is change do something else